# Kubectl patch service not updating loadBalancerIP

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl

I'm using this command to patch a K8s service to update its external IP address:

```
$ kubectl patch svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx -p '{"spec": {"loadBalancerIP": "104.154.109.191"}}'
```

This is documented here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/static-ip/#promote-ephemeral-to-static-ip

However, when I do:

```
$ kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
```

I don't see the `EXTERNAL-IP` column updated with the IP address I provided. It's still using the one that was automatically assigned when the service was created. I'm expecting it to have the IP address that I am passing it in the `patch` command.

Comment: where the Kubernetes hosted I mean aws, cloud provider etc?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to initiate the Ingress Controller with a `loadBalancerIP` of my choice, like so:

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=<your-IP4-IP-address>
```

Then you can define Ingress rules, like so:

```
kubectl create ingress demo --class=nginx --namespace dev --rule="my-subdomain.parentdomain.com/*=myCoolService:9999"
```

Having played with it a bit, I'd recommend creating an `ingress.yaml` file in your respective service instead of creating rules via CLI manually. It just streamlines the process.